# Should I commit after each SQL action, or do multiple actions and then commit? Which is more efficient?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, commit

I need some clarification on the SQL scenario of SQL commits.

FOr example:

```
    1)  DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column_name = 'value';
        COMMIT the above transaction;

    Versus

    2) 
         for (i...n){
            DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column_name ('value');
         }

         COMMIT after 'N' transactions..
```

Consider N >=10, In this case would the stress on the DB will be better compared to the 1st approach or would the 2nd approach will have the same effect as the 1st approach...
I know the best approach is pass multiple values IN clause... Just need to know if 2nd is better than the 1st one>?

Comment: The answers are going to be broad here. Delete in LOOP is not really beneficial, unless you have replication enabled for the table. leaving the database to handle is better. If your delete is too big, and the rows to be retained is lesser than to be deleted, consider truncating, after copying the required rows into a temp table. Other than that, frequent commit is not bad really. As it flushes the log off. Also, unrecoverable delete is better yet/

Comment: 1) is almost always faster (see the link Axel Pool posted in his comment to Stephen's answer). A bit nitpicking: you don't "commit after n transactions" - you commit after n **statements**. Each commit ends one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Committing for every N transactions is indeed faster and nicer to the database logging facilities. The trade-off is how much data are you willing to lose if you have to restart the process.

E.g., you have 10,000,000 batch rows to load. If the process crashes at row number 7,543,232, how many rows can you afford to have to load again?

And yes, you'd do a prepare statement with bind parameters (? marks) for the values and then just do an execute on the statement handle for each row of values.

Comment: Additionally, there is the trade-off of making your redo logs too big. You wouldn't want 10,000,000 rows in a single commit, either.

Comment: Comitting generates more undo and slows you down. [It isn't faster or nicer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022). Why wouldn't you want to commit 10 million rows at once? As long as you size your undo appropriately, why would that be a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm new to Oracle. In Informix, the rule of thumb was always to commit fairly frequently. I liked this newer link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_best_oracle_commit_frequency.htm